# How to set specific color to an SelectableLabel according to his value (RecycleView)?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to create a RecycleView that shows us a series of windows services from a remote server (obtained with winRM). Then manage them (start,stop,restart) directly from my kivy app in my workstation.

Currently, each of the Windows services retrieved from the remote server are stored in a dictionary.
key=name of the service and value=status of the service.

Ex:[{"Netman" : "Running"}])

I filled out the RecycleView like that:

```py
self.rv.data = [{"text":service+" ("+status+")"} for service, status in dictServiceStatus.items()]
```

RecycleView and SelectableLabel are defined like that in kv file:

```py
<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (.51, .153, .255, .3) if not self.selected else (.225, .1, .6, 0.3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Services>:

       ...

       RecycleView:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
            SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                height: self.minimum_height
                scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                multiselect: False
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: dp(2)
```

the result looks like this:

---

Service1 (Running)

---

Service2 (Stopped)

---

Service3 (Stopped)

...

But I'm not satisfied with that because each SelectableLabel have the same color (except if it is selected) and I want to set a red color for a stopped service and a green color for a start service.

How can i do that ?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested `if...else` statements and check for the specific string in `self.text` when the label is selected.

## Snippets

```
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1) if self.selected and 'Stopped' in self.text else (0, 1, 0, 1) if self.selected and 'Running' in self.text else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Ok, so everything happens in the if statement in kivy file, not in the python code Thanks